# How to get a report with donor retention rate

Tags: civireport

I am trying to figure out my organization's Donor Retention rate from last fiscal year or with the time parameters I choose.  For example, year-to-date retention rate, year before last fiscal year, etc.

Could you please point me in the right direction?
I am very, very new to Civi and have figured out a lot, but need a push on this one.

Thank you,
Shea

Answer (score 1):

Under reports - contribution reports you'll find LYBUNT and SYBUNT reports which is what it sounds like you're looking for. https://docs.civicrm.org/user/en/latest/contributions/reports-and-analysis/#contribution-reports

Also https://docs.civicrm.org/user/en/latest/the-user-interface/searching/#contributions-made-in-year-x-and-not-year-y

Answer (score 1):

Using SearchKit is another option that gives you more control over the results, but it's a little more technical. It's what we use to calculate donor retention rates.

So for example, you could search for:

- Contacts
- with Contact Contributions (required) with Financial Type as appropriate, Status = Completed, and Date Received = whatever range you want as the first period, using the Date Range is easiest here rather than Pick Date
- Group by Contact ID

This will give you how many contacts donated in a certain period. Now add to that same search another:

- Contact Contributions (required) with Financial Type, Status and Date Received = whatever range you want as the second period

Now this will give you the number of contacts who donated in both periods. Divide those two numbers and you have your retention rate.

You can save the first search and then make a copy for the second and save that again so you have two saved searches that you can just check whenever you need and divide the results.